# Получить дату сборки программы

Tags: c++, qt, дата, время, datetime

Как получить время и дату пересборки программы? Далее нужно выводить её в `label` виджета. Как понял нужно что-то в .pro файле писать, но вот что, пока не нашел. Есть идеи?

Comment: В pro-файле не пишется дата сборки. Дата сборки пишется в MZPE-заголовке, но оно легко подделывается.

Comment: Уже нашел способ, использовал стандартные макросы компилятора GCC для Visual Studio они теже. Использовал __DATE__ для получения даты компиляции и __TIME__ для получения времени компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мое решение:

```
ui->label->setText(trUtf8("Дата сборки программы: ") + __DATE__ + trUtf8(" в ")  + __TIME__);
```

Comment: `__DATE__`/`__TIME__` могут показать некорректное значение, если файл, в котором они используются не компилировался во время сборки.